# Insert an element at an arbitrary index in python list

Tags: python

```
def func04():
    my_list = []

    my_list.insert(400, "s400")

    my_list.insert(5, "s5")
    my_list.insert(2, "s2")
    my_list.insert(4, "s4")
    my_list.insert(1, "s1")
    my_list.insert(3, "s3")
    my_list.insert(0, "s0")

    # my_list.sort()
    print(f'my_list: {str(my_list)}')

>>> my_list: ['s0', 's400', 's1', 's5', 's3', 's2', 's4']
```

What is the logic behind this sequence in python? Can anyone clarify

Comment: Do you mean logic instead of login?

Comment: if you try to add something in index 400 but the list is shorter it will be added to the end. then same for index 5, etc... if you debug step by step you will see how elements are added and why you end in this order

Comment: Python lists can't have gaps in the middle. You can't set index 400 until you first set all the indexes up to 399. So if you try to insert beyond the end, it just inserts at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify an index that is larger than the list currently, then it will just append to the end of the list.

```py
my_list = []                 # []
my_list.insert(400, "s400")  # [s400]
my_list.insert(5, "s5")      # [s400, s5]
my_list.insert(2, "s2")      # [s400, s5, s2]
my_list.insert(4, "s4")      # [s400, s5, s2, s4]
my_list.insert(1, "s1")      # [s400, s1, s5, s2, s4]
my_list.insert(3, "s3")      # [s400, s1, s5, s3, s2, s4]
my_list.insert(0, "s0")      # [s0, s400, s1, s5, s3, s2, s4]
```